# Text replace in bind function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use `.replace()` in a bind function.

```
var input = $('textarea#input');
var output = $('textarea#output');

input.bind('keyup', function() {
    output.val(input.val().replace('.', ':'));
    output.val(input.val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/gm, ''));
});
```

Why doesn't this portion of the code work? `output.val(input.val().replace('.', ':'));`

http://jsfiddle.net/R6H6q/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `output` in second statement to get effect of `first`. As the first replace stores the result in *output (not input)* and next replace should be performed on out.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R6H6q/5/)**

```
 output.val(output.val().replace(/(\n|\r|\r\n)/gm, ''));
```